# MongoDB - Querying based on the value of a property of an array of objects

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object

Brand new to MongoDB. I'm having difficulty querying by a property of an object nested in an array.

I have the following data structure:

```
{
    "sales":[
        {
            "item":1234,
            "seller":"SellerA",
            "buyer":"BuyerA"
        },
        {
            "item":5678,
            "seller":"SellerB",
            "buyer":"SellerB"
        },
        {
            "item":1122,
            "seller":"SellerA",
            "buyer":"BuyerA"
        },
        {
            "item":1199,
            "seller":"SellerB",
            "buyer":"SellerB"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have other properties at the same level as the "sales" array, but I've simplified for the example.

I am attempting to pull every sales document which has a buyer value of "BuyerB."

I've tried the following:

```
db.data.find({"sales": {$elemMatch: {buyer: "BuyerB"}}})
db.data.find({"sales.buyer": "BuyerB"}})
```

These queries run, but return every row of data and not just the ones that have a buyer value of "BuyerB"

I know there has to be a simple answer, but what my searches have turned up is what I've already tried without success.

Comment: what is your desired output? pls clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may return more than one element from an array and **.find()** cannot do this, you can try **aggregate** such as:

```
db.c.aggregate({
    $match : {
        "sales.buyer" : "BuyerB"
    }
}, {
    $unwind : "$sales"
}, {
    $match : {
        "sales.buyer" : "BuyerB"
    }
}, {
    $group : {
        _id : "$_id",
        sales : {
            $push : "$sales"
        }
    }
});
```